# Cannot get access https and non-www redirect to testing httpd

Tags: http, ssl, https, server, virtualhost

I have problem cannot get https and non-www redirect to testing httpd. What should i do? The problem is

- I cannot access to https eventhough the certificate created successfully
- Why when i tried to access https://www works directly to my exact folder but non www direct to testing httpd?
- What's the different between www and non-www? There is big different www and non-www about anything or not?

This is my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

       <Directory /var/www/html/public>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.test.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried rerun the certbot, I choosed :

- 1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
- 2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access. Choose this for new sites, or if you're confident your site works on HTTPS. You can undo this change by editing your web server's configuration.

but i got an error

```
Failed redirect for test.com
Unable to set enhancement redirect for test.com
```